# accepts_nested_attributes_for not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, simple-form

I'm fairly new to rails, building my first app. I'm running rails 4 w/ bootstrap 3. I'm trying to get a complex form to work. I have two models:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :company
    belongs_to :user, :through => :company
    has_one :position
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :position
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employees
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :employees
end
```

I have a form where the User can create a new job title (Position Model) and select the employees (Employees Model) that position will be applied to. Basically it's a single form that will add fields to 2 different database tables (Position and Employee).

This is my view:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@position) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :job_title %>
    <%= f.input :job_description %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :Employee do |f| %>
        <%= f.input :employee_title, label: "Apply to:", collection: Employee.all, label_method: :first_name, as: :check_boxes %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Below are the controllers:

```
class PositionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_position, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /positions
  # GET /positions.json
  def index
    @positions = Position.all
  end

  # GET /positions/1
  # GET /positions/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /positions/new
  def new
    @position = Position.new
  end

  # GET /positions/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /positions
  # POST /positions.json
  def create
    @position = Position.new(position_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @position.save
        format.html { redirect_to @position, notice: 'position was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @position }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @position.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /positions/1
  # PATCH/PUT /positions/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @position.update(position_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @position, notice: 'position was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @position.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /positions/1
  # DELETE /positions/1.json
  def destroy
    @position.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to positions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_position
      @position = Position.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def position_params
      params.require(:position).permit(:position_title, :position_description, :position_create_date)
    end
end

class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
    # encoding: UTF-8
  before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  # GET /employees/1
  # GET /employees/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /employees/new
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  # GET /employees/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /employees
  # POST /employees.json
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1
  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /employees/1
  # DELETE /employees/1.json
  def destroy
    @employee.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employees_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_employee
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def employee_params
      params.require(:employee).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :employee_title)
    end
end
```

The problem I'm facing is I get the form to render perfectly, but when I submit it, only fields that belong to the Position model get recorded. The `:employee_title` stays blank. Any suggestions what the problem is?

Thank you!!

Comment: put your controller code too, if you are using strong parameter than make sure you are allowing all the parameters

Comment: Maybe it's something with the controllers. I've added both controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Too many points to fit in a comment:

`belongs_to :employees` should be singular: `belongs_to :employee`

Your `fields_for` should be like (differentiate the **ff** from parent form):

```
<%= f.fields_for :Employee do |ff| %>
<%= ff.input :employee_title, label: "Apply to:", collection: Employee.all, 
                            label_method: :first_name, as: :check_boxes %>
<% end %>
```

If it doesn't work, supply your controller also and I'll update my answer.

**Edit:**

After seeing your controllers, it seems most likely to be case of `unpermitted params`.

In `position_controller.rb` add employee params to position params

```
def position_params
  params.require(:position).permit(:position_title, :position_description, :position_create_date, employees_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :employee_title])
end
```

Comment: Ya, unfortunately that didn't work. I've added both controllers. Thanks

Comment: Updated after seeing your controllers.

Comment: For some reason that didn't work as well. Any other suggestion?

Comment: Well the unpermitted params was definitely one problem that is now fixed. Seems there's more. What error does it show in the console?

Comment: Here are the lines that might help: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/ShCbE3g46SUke2x2bJ3FHwR0QDN5JpCvGjbyNH6r6M=", "position"=>{"job_title"=>"handler", "job_description"=>"blabla", "Employee"=>{"employee_title"=>["1", ""]}}, "commit"=>"Update Position", "id"=>"8"}
  Job Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "positions".* FROM "positions" WHERE "positions"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "8"]]
Unpermitted parameters: Employee

Comment: `Unpermitted parameters: Employee` it is still case of unpermitted params. Did you replace `position_params` with my suggestion? Try it with singular `employee_attributes:` as I might have been confused how you formatted that model.

Comment: Yes, I replaced it with your suggestion and also tried plural/singular and still didn't work.

Comment: any other suggestion on how to fix that?

Comment: Yes, it is still there. Made all the changes possible and couldn't find a solution.